# Prevent parse-server to write logs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

is there a way to prevent parse-server to write logs file?
I'm using Google App engine standard environment and I don't have writing permission, so when parse-server tries to write a log file it crashes.
I've found this online:

> logsFolder: Folder for the logs (defaults to './logs'); set to
>   null to disable file based logging

but it's not working.
https://parseplatform.org/parse-server/api/3.1.0/ParseServerOptions.html

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to initialize Parse Server?

Comment: You can set silent: true, verbose: false.